# primefaces calender: how to set dynamically mindate

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, primefaces

I have two primefaces calender controls.I want that when I select a date from the first calender then next calender mindate should be start from 1st calender's selected date.For instance, I have selected `7/5/2013` then next calender should disable all dates before `8/5/2013`
This is what I have tried so far but it is not working

```
   <p:calendar id="fromD" value="#{requestController.from}" yearRange="2013:2015" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" mindate="#{requestController.today}"/>

<p:calendar id="toD" value="#{requestController.to}" yearRange="2013:2015" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" mindate="#{requestController.from}"/>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From `change` event , you can't submit the value of date.You need to change the event to `dateSelect` 
Just do

```
<p:ajax event="dateSelect" update="toD"/>
```

It will reset the mindate for your next calender/component

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to do the following:

```
<p:ajax event="dateSelect" update="toD" global="false" />
<p:ajax event="change" update="toD" global="false" />
```

It will reset the mindate on both events.